# 360 degree movement example in java

Tags: java, swing, rotation, rotateanimation

is it possible to simply make 360 degree movement in java(swing) without any game engine? all I have is this attempt:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    int x = 300;
    int y = 500;
    float angle = 30;
    Game game;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new Game());
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public Game() { 
    setSize(600, 600);

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    while(true) {
        angle += -0.1;
        x += Math.sin(angle);
        y--;
        repaint();
        try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
    }

}
```

as you can see in following picture, I don't know how to handle movement rotating, this is the output:

[image http://screenshot.cz/GOXE3/mvm.jpg](http://screenshot.cz/GOXE3/mvm.jpg)

Comment: I'm not doing 3D graphics, check the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change a few lines...

```
int basex = 300;   // midpoint of the circle
int basey = 400;
int radius = 100;  // radius
int x;
int y;
float angle = 0;  // Angles in radians, NOT degrees!

public void run() {
  while(true) {
    angle += 0.01;
    x  = (int)(basex + radius*Math.cos(angle));
    y  = (int)(basey - radius*Math.sin(angle));
    repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
  }
}
```

Not sure what you were trying to code there, but this is the correct formula for a circular movement.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is quite possible.

My preferred way is to actually take advantage of the `Graphics` transform so that you don't have to do any computation, it's all left to the `Graphics`

By the way:

- since you did not create the `Graphics` object, don't ever dispose it.
- override `paintComponent()` rather than `paint()`
- It's always a good pattern to call `super.paintComponent()`

Small demo example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestRotate {

    public static class ShapeAndColor {
        private final Shape shape;
        private final Color color;

        public ShapeAndColor(Shape shape, Color color) {
            super();
            this.shape = shape;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Shape getShape() {
            return shape;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

    }

    public static class RotatingShapesPanel extends JComponent {

        private List<ShapeAndColor> shapes;

        private double rotation = 0.0;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            AffineTransform translate = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(-getWidth() / 2, -getHeight() / 2);
            AffineTransform rotate = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotation);
            AffineTransform t = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            t.concatenate(rotate);
            t.concatenate(translate);
            g2d.setTransform(t);
            AffineTransform scale = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(getWidth(), getHeight());
            for (ShapeAndColor shape : shapes) {
                Area area = new Area(shape.getShape());
                g2d.setColor(shape.getColor());
                area.transform(scale);
                g2d.fill(area);
            }
        }

        public void setShapes(List<ShapeAndColor> shapes) {
            this.shapes = shapes;
            repaint();
        }

        public double getRotation() {
            return rotation;
        }

        public void setRotation(double rotation) {
            this.rotation = rotation;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    protected void initUI(final boolean useBorderLayout) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        List<ShapeAndColor> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double x = r.nextDouble();
            double y = r.nextDouble();
            double w = r.nextDouble();
            double h = r.nextDouble();
            w = Math.min(w, 1 - x) / 2;
            h = Math.min(h, 1 - y) / 2;
            double a = Math.min(w, h) / 10.0;
            RoundRectangle2D.Double shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h, a, a);
            Color color = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
            shapes.add(new ShapeAndColor(shape, color));
        }
        final RotatingShapesPanel panel = new RotatingShapesPanel();
        panel.setShapes(shapes);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer t = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double rotation = panel.getRotation() + 0.02;
                if (rotation > Math.PI * 2) {
                    rotation -= Math.PI * 2;
                }
                panel.setRotation(rotation);
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(true);
        t.setDelay(10);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestRotate().initUI(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You program has some problems:

```
int x = 300;
int y = 500;
```

You should use a floating point data type like `double` to store the coordinates. You can cast them to `int` when you want to draw them. If you store them in `int`, you'll lose precision.

```
x += Math.sin(angle);
y--;
```

This doesn't work, since `y` is decremented instead of calculated using `Math.sin(angle)`. (us `Math.cos` for `x`)

This is your fixed code (unchanged parts are omitted):

```
double x = 300;
double y = 500;
float angle = 30;
double radius = 10D; // new variable to increase the radius of the drawn circle
Game game;

// main method

// constructor

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // ... stuff omitted
    g.fillOval((int)x, (int)y, 10, 10); // you can cast to int here
    g.dispose();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        angle -= 0.1; // is the same as `angle += -0.1`
        x += radius * Math.cos(angle);
        y += radius * Math.sin(angle);
        repaint();
        // ... try catch block
    }
}
```

This currenlty draw the circle counter-clockwise. If you want to draw it clockwise, then change angle to:

```
angle += 0.1;
```

Comment: This is wrong because the angle must be in radians, and cosine goes with x and sine goes with y. It's also fine to have x and y as `ints`, but your code will be rotating x and y around the point (0, 0).

Comment: @DavidConrad `but your code will be rotating x and y around the point (0, 0)` It will rotate around the initial coordinate of `x` and `y`. And you're right, `sin` and `cos` are currently switched.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you used `+=`.

Comment: @DavidConrad And that is why I used `double` :P. You used a separate variable for that. But I generally prefer storing coordinates using a floating point data type, even on pixel based systems.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the rotation around a point, you need a center point for the rotation (cx, cy), the radius or distance of the point from the center, you need the angle (in radians, not degrees), and you need to use sine and cosine to calculate the offset of the point from the center as it rotates around it.

```
int cx, cy, radius; // I'll let you determine these
double theta = Math.toRadians(30);
double dtheta = Math.toRadians(-0.1);

double dx = Math.cos(theta) * radius;
double dy = Math.sin(theta) * radius;
int x = (int)(cx + dx);
int y = (int)(cy + dy);

repaint();
theta += dtheta; // step the angle
```